# Azure Logic App throwing 302 Redirect Error having Server=BIG IP in Response Header for HTTP

Tags: access-token, azure-logic-apps, http-status-code-302

I am getting Redirect 302 error for HTTP Request in Logic App. I am calling OneIdentityServer to get access token. Then I am calling Rest API passing access token as Header for key Authorization. I am getting 302 Redirect error in response  with headers information like Server = BIG IP, Location= /my.policy

The same above request when triggered through Postman or SOAPUI is working fine, I am getting successful response. But the same is failing in Azure Logic App.

I have also implemented the above scenario in function app as well. It is working file when I run the function app code from visual studio using Postman. But when I test the same function app after publishing it to Azure portal, it is giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have the same issue as you. I found one-way that did not work for me but maybe you could give it a shot if it fits your needs?

The solution that I found in a blogpost was first to add the action "Switch" to the logic app flow and then configure Switch to run after the HTTP is both successful and has failed.

Secondly, the Switch action should trigger on the output of the statuscode from the HTTP request.
If the statuscode equals 302 you should make another HTTP request but with URI being the output of the location header from the first HTTP request. This made my logic app result in statuscode 200 but the response for my logic app was that I needed to login to get access to the API.

But maybe it could be worth giving this solution a shot for your logic app?

Here's the link of the blogpost if you need deeper instructions: http://www.alessandromoura.com.br/2018/11/21/dealing-with-http-302-in-logic-apps/

Comment: For me, the issue were in the HTTP step where I acquire the token. 
In the field "resource" where you specify what kind of resource you want the token to be used for I had missed an slash ( / ) at the end of the url. So if you want to acquire a token for graph api in Microsoft you would use the graph.microsoft.com url but you need to remember the trailing slash for it to correctly acquire a token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did tried the solution from the blogpost which you mentioned in the response. But it is not working for me. The token service is working fine for me but the problem is using the access token from above service when I call the Rest API , I am getting 302 error. The REST API is GET method and have some dynamic value at the end of url.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have issues with this? Here is a screenshot of my http action: [HTTP Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duoXv.png) that is working.
I have put my URL in an variable since it changing for each pagination. I also found out that to use the authentication token from the first HTTP request I needed to parse the body to be able to access the token, here is the schema I used to parse the HTTP body from the request where you get access token:

```
{
"properties": {
    "access_token": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "expires_in": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "expires_on": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "ext_expires_in": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "not_before": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "resource": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "token_type": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"type": "object"
}
```