# How to handle BIG-IP redirects in Logic App?

Tags: redirect, azure-logic-apps, big-ip

Please would anyone help guide me on how to handle redirects when trying to GET to a HTTPS Endpoint? The Logic App is to GET the status of this external/third-party HTTPS Endpoint (includes Basic authentication). This HTTPS Endpoint has got F5 BIG-IP which redirects to /my.policy and provides cookies.

When I try this through Postman, it works fine as Postman handles the redirects. BIG-IP is doing two redirect for this single query.

Please how can this be achieved in Logic App (Standard)?

Answer (score 0):

Use Http trigger or action based on your requirement to redirect api in logic app.

- As shown in below image, taken an http action and selected method type as Get.
- Enter https endpoint url in URI.
  [image]
- Pass the headers same as you are passing in postman request.
- Send body and cookie details also if it is required in your Get request call.
- In Add new parameter, select authentication type.
- There will be multiple authentication types like basic, none, client certificate, AD OAuth, raw and managed identity.

Below is referral [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60885945/azure-logic-app-throwing-302-redirect-error-having-server-big-ip-in-response-hea). Check if it helps in your case,

Comment: Hi Vijaya, I have already tried this. The problem is that the external HTTPS endpoint that I am calling has got Policy Access Manager in front which redirects to another location, along with the cookie. At this point, the Logic app HTTP request fails (with 302) without getting redirected. In Postman, the HTTP request gets automatically redirected and completes successfully. How can I achieve the same in Logic app? Thank you.

Comment: once try this   take an **HTTP action**in your logic app that makes the initial request to the external HTTPS endpoint then 
 a **Parse JSON action** to parse the Set-Cookie header from the response then  an **Variables action** to store the parsed cookie value in a variable then  take another HTTP action to make a subsequent request to the redirected location  passing the cookie value in a Cookie  header.